# Marklogic entity dictionary

Tags: dictionary, entity, marklogic

I have created entity dictionary following this documentation:
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/entity

The insertion done successfully ,but when I want to see the dictionary that I have created using :
`cts:entity-dictionary-get()`

it returns some code `<0x36d>` not the dictionary.
The documentation doesn't tell how to get and view the dictionary as a table, XML, or any format.

I figured out that dictionary is stored as a document since I can delete it using `document-delete()`, but I cant open it using `fn:doc()`.

Any help how can I see the inserted dictionary entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer.
I figured out that the dictionary stored as binary file, so I use

`xdmp:binary-decode(fn:doc("path"),"UTF-8")`

The dictionary showed as a table.

Comment: Be sure to mark your answer as accepted